# Angular Dynamic forms with api data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-dynamic-components

Do we have any best examples to create a dynamic forms from the data ? Which input fileds always dynamic. The use case I'm looking for is I have api which is having set of records which always not really consist means today if have 20 record tomrrow may increase upto another 20 ,with this scenario do we have any sort of forks ?

Comment: Are you referring to this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form Or something else?

Comment: Hi,okay, this is my current approach as reactive forms , I built the form with 20 input files as form group and controls for the one record which comes from api which is built on mongo collection ,my record insertion is always dynamic, today I built a form with 20 records ,but tomorrow if the new record comes with more or less I have to populate the form .with my current approach is static which means when ever new record eitj new fileds are inserted I need to tweak my form code to render the values. so with this what is the best way to achieve dynamic forms. Appreciate if you have any magic.

Answer (score 1):

We use the ngx-formly module for rendering forms using json schema. It is a very vast library with awesome community support and a whole lot of features. You just need to pass your json schema in a specific format and the form will be rendered with all validations.

https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly GitHub - ngx-formly/ngx-formly: JSON powered / Dynamic forms

Comment: Thank you much prasheel,gald that I got it on time , does this works  with mat dialog Data?. Meaning I have two components , component A renders the table data from api and  component B servers larger  part of records in dialog form .

Comment: @vijaymunnangi Yes, it should work in that case as well.